# how to use gazetteer features as input in other models with BILOU

Tags: nlp, entity, named-entity-recognition

I was working on a gazetteer list to use for NER tagging but with CRF or LSTM models. I had a doubt if I have a bigram as a gazetteer then do both individual words have the feature as 1 ? For example I saw "Bring Apple Juice" and Apple Juice is in gazetteer list for Products then do both Apple and Juice have an entry of 1 or only the second word Juice has it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should follow IOB format for NER tagging like below.

```
Eddy N B-PER
Bonte N I-PER
is V O
woordvoerder N O
van Prep O
diezelfde Pron O
Hogeschool N B-ORG
. Punc O
```